# What is the pixel size that corresponds to a 24'' and 32'' monitor?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resolution

I'm writing an application that I need to optimize for different monitor sizes so that the components & divs don't appear super large (such as when your resolution isn't set to it's recommended setting).

What @media directive corresponds to a 24'', and what corresponds to a 32'' monitor?

Comment: There's no relation between pixels and screen size.

Comment: How can I achieve what I'm setting out to do? (optimizing the sizes of components according to the screen size)

Comment: Maybe you can adjust your components based on `wv` or `vh`?